# Postgresql - how to disallow use of spaces in some string fields

Tags: database, postgresql, plperl

I want to disallow the use of spaces in some text/varchar fields.

Even more, it would be best to have only a set of characters that are allowed to use there, like:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]
```

And I want to make it as a rule to all `VARCHAR` fields that are members of `primary key` in their tables.

This should be done on the database level and could throw an exception when trying to insert a wrong record or update one with a change of a key field to invalid value.

Can this be done within the database level? Should I use `Pl/Perl` for that, or is there any simpler method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't even need stored procedures:

```
alter table xxx add constraint check_valid_chars check ( your_column ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+$' );
```

should work.

Comment: Ok. Any way to automate this for N tables, each with 1+ fields to be altered? like: for each table { for each field in table that is a key { alter } }

Comment: requires scripting but the key to your task is in the `information_schema.`

Comment: Check my blogpost on "grantall" : http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/10/19/grantall/ - the technique I used there can be applied in this case as well.

Comment: I just used `your_column !~ ' '`.

Comment: I believe that won't account for other blank space characters, like Tabs and Carriage Returns

Answer (score 4):

You can define a domain, look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdomain.html at the bottom, there is an example about US postal code.

Comment: This looks promising, but it requires altering all my existing data, which is quite a lot of tables. I was thinking more of a way to inject into my existing database, that's why I thought of a trigger and function first.

Comment: this does NOT require altering all your data, only schema.
DOMAINs are designed precisely for this.

`ALTER TABLE foo ALTER bar TYPE my_domain;`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your latest comment you could perhaps use CHECK constraints and regex search?
But you will have to modify the schema (tables) and insert it for each field.